How to apply an expression from a column to another column in pyspark dataframe?
I would like to know if it is possible to apply.
for example, I have this table:
new_feed_dt regex_to_apply  expr_to_apply               
053021  | _(\d+)        | date_format(to_date(new_feed_dt, 'yyyyMMdd'), 'yyyy-MM-dd')               
053022  | _(\d+)        | date_format(to_date(new_feed_dt, 'yyyyMMdd'), 'yyyy-MM-dd')               
053023  | _(\d+)        | date_format(to_date(new_feed_dt, 'yyyyMMdd'), 'yyyy-MM-dd')               
053024  | [a-zA-Z]+(\d+) | date_format(to_date(new_feed_dt, 'MMddyyyy'), 'yyyy-MM-dd')              
053025  | DT(\d+)       | date_format(to_date(new_feed_dt, 'MMddyy'), 'yyyy-MM-dd')             

I need to use this expr to apply the column to the date column.
Example image:

I tried so far this but it didn't work.
df_with_regex.withColumn(
        'new_feed_dt',
        f.expr("expr_to_apply")
    )

How would you do it?
Thanks in advance!

Try this:
for row in df_with_regex.collect():
    df_with_regex = df_with_regex.withColumn(
        'new_feed_dt_transformed',
        f.expr(row['expr_to_apply']).alias('new_feed_dt_transformed')
    )
df.show(truncate=False)

# +-----------+--------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------+
# |new_feed_dt|regex_to_apply|expr_to_apply                                              |new_feed_dt_transformed|
# +-----------+--------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------+
# |053021     |_(\d+)        |date_format(to_date(new_feed_dt, 'yyyyMMdd'), 'yyyy-MM-dd')|2021-05-30             |
# |053022     |_(\d+)        |date_format(to_date(new_feed_dt, 'yyyyMMdd'), 'yyyy-MM-dd')|2022-05-30             |
# |053023     |_(\d+)        |date_format(to_date(new_feed_dt, 'yyyyMMdd'), 'yyyy-MM-dd')|2023-05-30             |
# |053024     |[a-zA-Z]+(\d+)|date_format(to_date(new_feed_dt, 'MMddyyyy'), 'yyyy-MM-dd')|2024-05-30             |
# |053025     |DT(\d+)       |date_format(to_date(new_feed_dt, 'MMddyy'), 'yyyy-MM-dd')  |2025-05-30             |
# +-----------+--------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------+

